# Is there a way to implement AMP-Story in Blogger?

Tags: blogger, amp-html

i have seen the **[amp-story](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-story/)** is not allowed to have any sibling tags **('body' should only have 1 child)**.
is there a way to implement amp-story in blogger?
i.e, blogger post contain lot of **`<div>`** tags and classes like wrapper item, wide inside **`<body>`**
should i change the code inside body tag in template?

Comment: have you tried this: https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/integrate/embed-stories/

Comment: yes i have tried but i need amp story in blogger post  like AMP-blogger post